# How can I fix a malfunctioning optical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, gaming, cleaning

I've been using [this keyboard](https://smile.amazon.com/Keyboard-Mechanical-Feedback-Ergonomic-Floating/dp/B0734919BR/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=1U5F1TH2U29VX&keywords=bloody%20keyboard&qid=1567542459&s=gateway&sprefix=bloody%20keyboard%2Caps%2C205&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFCTVBERkhWQzBTTEImZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA2MzAzNjgyRVdEMURUQ1VWSlhHJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA4NTIwMzExRjRCVzlBNkhNT0hOJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) for a few years now; it's technically a "gaming" keyboard, but I find great use in it for programming and 3D modeling as well. Most of the keys are optical and high-sensitivity, and my fingers are now accustomed to its key placement.

However, as of recently, I've been having trouble using the numeric -, +, and enter buttons, as well as the letter B. For some time they won't work at all, and then some time later I'll get spammed with a long sequence of each of them.

This persists after a cold boot, so I can rule out software. I can also rule out interference from my mouse, my graphics tablet, and my game controller, as switching to an older keyboard has temporarily stopped the issue. (However, I really would like to get that one up and running again.)

Over the past few years, to expand, this thing has taken a few hard falls from a failing keyboard tray, and has been basically immersed in free-floating house cat hair. I removed all of the keys and cleaned under them, and got quite a bit of fur out of it, but the problem itself persists.

My best suspicion is that there's a refractive cat hair somewhere in the light channel, which is occasionally sputtering a bit and giving false positives on +, -, numeric enter, and more mysteriously B. However, I'm not sure how to get to it to clean it out. Has anyone encountered a problem like this with a high-sensitivity optical keyboard before? If so, what should I consider doing to try and fix it?

(ADDENDUM: If it's relevant, my desktop OS is usually Mint 19.1. I have Windows 7 on here too but haven't had a reason to actually boot it in months. It is a desktop tower, not a laptop. The keyboard is, now, externally spotless and cat fur free. The malfunctioning keyboard and the old Logitech I'm using in place of it both plugged into the same USB slot on the back of the machine, so I can probably rule out problems with that, too. And, yes, the Bloody™ gaming keyboard connects by wire, not Bluetooth or wireless frequency, and its internal optical channel is in the infrared range.)

Thanks for the read and I appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: Did you check the manufacturer website or talk to them?  There may be a cleaning guide.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, I haven't done that yet. I'll look into it this evening.

Comment: The site simply suggests blasting it out with compressed air every 90 days or so, and to be fair, it was overdue. I don't have a lot of it left but there's a hardware store down the street; I'll see about emptying a can into it and see if I can get it to behave again.

Comment: Sorry for you @MichaelMacha, too late comment but I'm also having same issue with my HP Omen Sequencer Optical keyboard. No solution yet. Seems board issue. Disassembled completely and cleaned with compressed air as well as alcohol. My "K" key repeats. Stops repeating for some time if I press it multiple times.

Comment: @Ghazi Alcohol is a good idea, I ended up using it on this thing too. It didn't work immediately and I had to switch to an old keyboard while I let it dry in a clean, cat-hair-free area. After a few days I popped all the keys back on and got it working again.

If it's just your 'K' key, are you sure it isn't an issue with the spring mechanism on the button? The HP Omen is a laptop, isn't it?

Comment: It isn't mechanism issue as switches are swappable and I swapped too. Tried alcohol too. No debris issue seems. Randomly occured. I ended up buying a corsair keyboard. :)

Comment: @Ghazi Hey, I'm glad you fixed it somehow. I mean, Ks are important. I'm just thinking that if it's specifically the K key, there's probably something refracting or blocking the light in there.